# [C]undefined reference while compiling openCL program

Tags: c, include, compilation, opencl

I'm trying to compile something to try out openCl, but i'm having a few problems..

Here the code

prova.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <CL/opencl.h>
#include "Utils\util.h"
#include <malloc.h>

int main(){
    cl_int error = 0;   // Used to handle error codes
    cl_int max_platforms = 1; // The maximum number of platforms
    cl_uint adviable_platforms = 0; //The adviable number of platforms
    cl_platform_id* platform;

    error = clGetPlatformIDs(0, NULL, &adviable_platforms);
    if(adviable_platforms == 0)
    {
        printf("No adviable platforms.\n");
        return -1;
    } else {
        platform = (cl_platform_id*)malloc(adviable_platforms * sizeof(cl_platform_id));
    }

    error = clGetPlatformIDs(adviable_platforms, platform, NULL);


    printf("clGetPlatformIDs: %s\n", clErrorString(error));
    return 0;
}
```

I'm compiling on win 7 64 with mingw32. The opencl headers are in the include directory of mingw while utils.h(inside the directory Utils inside the directory of prova.c)  defines clErrorString(that simply convert the error into a more human readable string).

To compile i use

```
gcc -L\Utils prova.c
```

But i always get

```
C:\[stuff]\ccEjYQbj.o:prova.c:(.text+0x42): undefined reference to 'clGetPlatformIDs@12'
C:\[stuff]\ccEjYQbj.o:prova.c:(.text+0x8d): undefined reference to 'clGetPlatformIDs@12'
C:\[stuff]\ccEjYQbj.o:prova.c:(.text+0x9e): undefined reference to 'clErrorString'
```

I'm not so good with compilers, so i image i'm missing something, but i really don't know what..

EDIT:
Sincerely, i tried every command come to my mind. using -L to include directories, -l to link to files, using ar..

This is the last "script" i tried

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python26;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\lib

cd Utils
gcc -c util.c -l"C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\lib\x86_64\libOpenCL.a" -o util.o
ar rcs libutil.a util.o

cd..
pause

gcc -c prova.c -l"Utils\libutil.a" -o prova.exe

pause
```

EDIT2:

```
@echo off
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python26;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\lib

cd Utils
gcc -Wall -c util.c -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\lib\x86_64\" -o util.o
ar rcs libutil.a util.o

cd..
pause

gcc -Wall -c prova.c -L"C:\Program Files (x86)\AMD APP\lib\x86_64\" -l"Utils\libutil.a" -o prova.exe

pause
```

No errors, the only warning is max_platform is unused. Then i find util.o and libutil.a(size 5kb) in Utils and prova.o(size 1kb). If i try to run prova.o, it says that the file version is not compatible with the current windows version, check the system version (x86 or x64) and contact the software distributor

Comment: That's a linker error, not a compiler error. You need to link in the OpenCL library.

Comment: Look in the mingw "lib" directory and see if you can find some sort of CL library (perhaps something named "libcl*.a"). Then pass the name (minus the "lib" and the ".a") to the compiler via "-l<name>".

Comment: opencl.h(and all other headers) is inside C:\Mingw\include\CL.I can't find something(opencl related) with opencl or cl in the name inside the lib folder or in the project folder.I know it is a noob question, but how i compile the header? I always thought headers don't get compiled, but only .c/.cpp files..Ps: i already tried to compile adding -lpath_to_include_folder, but got the same error.PPS: using the cmake script for a small program i got from the net it compiles just fine(i needed to remove the relative path to cl.h, since mine was in standard dir), so there is everything in my system..

Comment: @Kerrek SB
i tried `cd Utils
gcc -c util.c -o util.o \n
ar rcs libutil.a util.o \n

cd.. \n
pause \n

gcc -c prova.c -l"Utils\util" -o prova.exe\n

pause\n` but the executable is still 1kb size (while libutil.a is 5kb) and it still doesn't work (since, due to the dimension, i think ocl isn't included)

Comment: @Makers_F: Are you sure about your last command? `-l` takes a library name, not a directory, are you thinking of `-L`? And you're still not linking against the opencl library.

Comment: @Kerrek SB edited the message to add the last code i tried to compile.. Can you write me and example on how to compile a really simple program that includes just an header(without the relative .c/.cpp file) All over the net i find examples including .c and the relative header

Comment: @Makers: If your last line indicates the correct relative locations, then try `gcc -c prova.c "Utils\libutil.a" -o prova.exe`. You don't need to use `-l` for static libraries, you just specify them like ordinary object files. (If you say `-lname`, the linker looks for a file `libname.a` or `libname.so`.)

Comment: @Kerrek SB tried and got none.. It compiles without errors, but still doesn't link, and when i start the program it says that it is not compatible with current win version( i never got this error before, with any program)

Comment: @Makers_F: What do you mean "it doesn't link"? Do you get any errors, and from which program? Maybe can you post more detailed output of the operations you perform?

Comment: @Kerrek SB Edited the first post

Comment: @Makers_F: Option `-l` does not work the way you think. Check the manual, or my post above. Option `-c` also doesn't work the way you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
set PATH=%PATH%;C:\Python26;C:\MinGW\bin;C:\MinGW\lib

cd Utils
gcc -W -Wall -c util.c -o util.o
ar rcs libutil.a util.o

cd..

gcc -W -Wall -c prova.c -o prova.o
gcc -o prova.exe prova.o Utils\libutil.a

# Using a standard library
gcc -o prog.exe myprog.o -lzip  # e.g. /usr/lib/libz.a

# Using a nonstandard library
gcc -o prog.exe myprog.o -lfoo -L/tmp/libfoo  # uses /tmp/libfoo/libfoo.a
gcc -o prog.exe myprog.o /tmp/libfoo/libfoo.a # same effect
```

In general:

- Compile single source files with `-c`:
  `gcc -c myfile.c -o myfile.o`.
  This creates *object* files.
- Link all the object files to an executable (or shared library):
  `gcc -o prog.exe myfile.o yourstuff.o sha257.o`
- You can combine object files into a *static* library, which you treat just like a single object file when linking:
  `ar rcs libcoolstuff.a yourstuff.o sha257.o`
  `gcc -o prog.exe myfile.o libcoolstuff.a`
  Alternatively:
  `gcc -o prog.exe myfile.o -lcoolstuff`
  The latter syntax (automatic library linking with `-l`) requires either `libcoolstuff.a` or `libcoolstuff.so` to be findable in the library path (which you can amend with `-L` at linktime).

Comment: Really good explanation!!With this i managed to compile a really simple project(that i wrote to test it)that includes a source including another source,and i managed to compile and link them.Than i tried with the openCL program.Compiling went just fine,but at link time i got "undefinde reference". I used `gcc -W -Wall -c util.c -o util.o \n cd.. gcc -W -Wall -c prova.c - prova.o \n gcc -o prova.exe prova.o Utils\util.o` For sure i'm still missing to add the opencl libraries. But they are in standard location (i include them with <CL\opencl.h>, so what should i add? Btw thank you for the help!

Comment: Ps: and thank you for clarifying the use of the gcc commands!!

Comment: @Makers_F: I added some examples for using libraries from other paths. If you use the `-l` syntax, you can specify additional library search paths with `-L`.

Comment: WoooooW| You're so cool! I managed to compile it! In the AMD APP folder i found a libOpenCl.a, and including this, with your (great) help, i managed to run the program. What i don't still understand is why should i link an external library when i already include the openCL headers inside my program(and the preprocessor should add them).. And how do they(AMD) get this library? I can't compile a header file.. Btw, now it works!! Thank you so much for all the time spent with me!!

Comment: @Makers_F: You should think about the compilation and linking process a bit. The headers only tell the compiler that a function `int foo();` _exists_ somewhere, but it doesn't tell it what this function actually _is_. The compiler can generate code that _uses_ `foo`, but that code will still have an unresolved symbol for `foo` rather than actual code. It's the linker's job to fetch all the code for the unresolved symbols and make one single self-contained executable. And the implementation of the library functions are in the library `.a` file. There is no actual code in the headers!